# Rails.logger and New Relic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I a have Ruby app running on heroku and use New Relic for monitoring. I like any instance of an Error Log to appear in New Relic Event > Alerts.

Is that possible? I tried many ways but none yielded any alert at all.

Is there a different way to trigger an alert from my rails app?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use the REST-api (https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/getting-started-with-the-new-relic-rest-api) or even handle it with the ruby-agent advanced features (https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-api)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to create an alert with the API? I don't see any service call for that.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of using the API for creating alerts can be found here: https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/alert-api-examples

Comment: "Alert API- New Relic's REST API allows you to configure alert settings. This includes enabling and disabling alerts for applications and servers, as well as getting and setting alert thresholds." -- it doesn't seem to provide a way of triggering an alert, just configuring  ones. Do I misunderstand that?