# can an app monitored by New Relic explicitly generate an incident alert from inside itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, newrelic

I'm using New Relic (Heroku add-on) to monitor a Rails app. There is a place in the app that detects a "this should never happen" condition that's not easily detectable via New Relic's monitoring, and I'd like to be able to use New Relic notifications/alerts/whatever to immediately send up a flare in that code path. Is there a way to explicitly trigger an alert from within an app, so that I don't have to add another gem/plugin just for incident alerts?

(This seems similar to [this 2013 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17513605/558723) that was never definitively answered and whose links in comments are now stale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```rb
begin
  this_should_never_happen
rescue Exception
  if defined?(NewRelic)
    error = StandardError.new('Boom!')
    NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(error)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like `NewRelic::Agent.notice_error` is what I was looking for, especially since it appears it can be used outside a `begin..rescue..end` as well. (In my case, the code is looking for some specific database inconsistencies after the fact, so the call to `notice_error` would probably **not** be the result of rescuing an exception.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NewRelic::Agent.record_custom_event](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/NewRelic/Agent#record_custom_event-instance_method) or [NewRelic::Agent.notice_error](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/NewRelic/Agent#notice_error-instance_method.) methods.